# filter list/library by 2013 workflow status

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, filter

I am looking for  a way to filter a list by a share point designer 2013 workflow. I can filter fine using a 2010 workflow however 2013 workflows do not appear on the filter options (although they do for other view options such as group by).

Is there a way (using views, JS or custom urls) that will allow me to filter a list based on the status of a 2013 workflow (such as completed, error occurred, etc)?

Comment: Filtering in view?

Comment: It does not seem to let me in the same way it does for a 2010 workflow. The 2013 workflow columns do not have any results to filter by.